# reading JSON dictionary in python: how to handle array of length 1?

Tags: python, arrays, json

I need to read a JSON message that has a key called "derivedFrom". Its value might have either this form:

```
Case 1. "derivedFrom": "id1"
```

or this:

```
Case 2. "derivedFrom": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
```

What I need to do is something very basic: read the value(s) and loop over them. Right now I am doing this:

```
#line contains JSON string
data = json.loads(line)
# ...
derivedIds = data['derivedFrom']
for deid in derivedIds:
# ...
```

This works fine for Case 2 but for Case 1 it loops over individual characters of the id "id1" which is clearly not what I need.

How do I modify the block above to handle both cases correctly? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that derivedFrom's value will *always* be a list or a value (that is, not a dict):

```
#line contains JSON string
data = json.loads(line)
# ...
derivedIds = data['derivedFrom']
if not isinstance(derivedIds, list):
    derivedIds = [derivedIds]
for deid in derivedIds:
```

The fact that it's coming from JSON simplifies matters as it greatly restricts the number of datatypes you have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with the fact that `str/unicode` don't have an `__iter__` attribute, whereas `lists`, `sets` or `dicts` do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import json

case1 = '{"derivedFrom": "id1"}'

case2 = '{"derivedFrom": ["id1", "id2", "id3"]}'

def parse(line):
    data = json.loads(line)
    if not(hasattr(data["derivedFrom"], "__iter__")):
        print "Converting %s to list" % type(data["derivedFrom"])
        data["derivedFrom"] = [data["derivedFrom"]]
    print "data['derivedFrom']: %s, of type %s" % (data["derivedFrom"], type(data["derivedFrom"]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse(case1)
    parse(case2)
```

Although, if possible, I would prefer modifying whatever is sending that JSON to ensure that is sending lists (trying to make it send `'{"derivedFrom": ["id1"]}'`)

Answer (score 0):

As primitive example:

```
#line contains JSON string
data = json.loads(line)
# ...
derivedIds = data['derivedFrom']
if isinstance(derivedIds, basestring):
   #.... 
else:
    for deid in derivedIds:
    # ...
```